# Weird behavior when using System.err.println()

Tags: java, stream, system.out, system.err

I thought that difference between `System.out.println()` and `System.err.println()` is simply in how messages are printed to console. Meaning `err` prints error messages (red color), while `out` prints standard messages. It has come to my notice that they are less alike than expected (for example, err messages would be **always** printed before out messages).

But there is one example I am particularly confused about. Say I have this simple program:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    if (num > 0) {
        System.out.println("All good, bye");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Number must be possitive!");
        System.out.print("New try:");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT (from my testing):

[image]

---

But when I make literally same code and just change message "Number must be possitive" to be printed using `System.err.println()`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    if (num > 0) {
        System.out.println("All good, bye");
        break;
    } else {
        System.err.println("Number must be possitive!");
        System.out.print("New try:");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT (from my testing):

[image]

I can't figure out how it is making these weird prints. Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Add `System.err.flush();` after `System.err.println("Number must be possitive!");`.

Comment: @saka1029 It doesn't help

Comment: This is a problem cause by your IDE. If you run the code in a command prompt / terminal window, it will print correctly. Don't mix output to stdout and stderr when the output needs to be read by another program (like an IDE).

Comment: `System.out` is buffered: `System.err` is not.

Comment: @user207421 are you sure that is (always(even?)) the case? eclipse is using a `BufferedOutputStream` for **both** here - same also true for command line Java (Java 1.8.0_202)

Comment: There are a couple of possible explanations, depending on what provides the console you are writing to; e.g. an IDE, a terminal emulator, etc.  But the bottom line is that the interspersing of `out` and `err` output is not 100% reliable across all platforms.  This is not actually Java's fault.  See the dup links for more information.

Comment: Positive*. 1 "s".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because two separate streams writing to same console.

```
int i = 5;
while (--i>0) {
        System.out.println("Number must be possitive!");
        System.out.println("New try:");
}

System.out.println("\n\n with two separate streams \n");
i=5;
while (--i>0) {
    System.err.println("Number must be possitive!");
    System.out.println("New try:");
}
```

Output:

```
Number must be possitive!
New try:
Number must be possitive!
New try:
Number must be possitive!
New try:
Number must be possitive!
New try:


 with two separate streams 

Number must be possitive!
New try:
New try:
Number must be possitive!
Number must be possitive!
New try:
Number must be possitive!
New try:
```

As both streams are not in synch the order in which they write is not guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest checking your IDE settings when it comes to console.
It happens to be running just fine for me:

[image: Example of mine compilation]

The code that I used is basically same:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        if (num > 0) {
            System.out.println("All good, bye");
            break;
            
        } else {
            System.err.println("Number must be possitive!");
            System.out.print("New try:");
            
        }
        
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting.